# Upgrading leanback version to 25.0.1 causes guidedStepFragment to crash

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

My android tv app works fine with these versions:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-leanback-v17:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.2.1'
```

But once I upgrade them to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-leanback-v17:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:25.0.1'
```

I see a crash everytime I open a guidedStepFragment. Here are the crash logs:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{...}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file
>   line #18: Invalid float: "?2130772240"
>                                                                                                        at 
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18:
>   Invalid float: "?2130772240"
>                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GuidedActionsStylist.onCreateView(GuidedActionsStylist.java:409)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v17.leanback.app.GuidedStepFragment.onCreateView(GuidedStepFragment.java:1044)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6267)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)

The app crashes while creating a view (onCreateView) for guidedStepFragment.

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Switched to 25.0.1 yersterday. Didn't get any issues yet

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using my own custom style for GuidedStepFragment that inherits from Theme.LeanbackBase.

Instead I made my custom style to inherit from Theme.Leanback.GuidedStep .This change fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [Adding a Guided Step](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/guided-step.html) wherein it mentions about the use of [android.support.v17.leanback.app](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/package-summary.html) that supports classes for building Leanback user experiences. As mentioned in the documentation,

> Leanback contains a mixture of higher level building blocks such as Fragments in the `android.support.v17.leanback.app` package. Notable examples are the [`BrowseFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.html) and the [`GuidedStepFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/GuidedStepFragment.html).

And, in addition to that, these references might also help:

- [Working with GuidedStepFragments on Android TV](http://peirr.com/working-with-guidedstepfragments-on-android-tv/)
- [Example on how to use the GuidedStepFragment in the Leanback library for Android TV](https://github.com/ckurtm/GuidedStepsTV)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the incompatibility of the Activity from the support library version of less than 17 with GuidedStepFragment from the support library "android.support.v17.leanback".

Use Activity from the "android.app.Activity":

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v17.leanback.app.GuidedStepFragment;

public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            GuidedStepFragment.addAsRoot(
                this, new YourGuidedStepFragment(), android.R.id.content
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Also use Theme.Leanback for your Activity:

```
<manifest...>
    <application...>
        <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"
        />
    </application>
</manifest>
```